# Why version is not printable?

Tags: perl, version, versioning

I have this one liner:

`perl -Mversion -e 'our $VERSION = v1.02; print $VERSION'`

The output is (It is not visible, there is two characters: 1, 2):

[image]

Why module version is not printable? I expect to see `v1.02`

Comment: I get output. It's two unprintable characters. I think i's 00 and 11

Comment: Doubles quotes around `v1.02` and it will be fine

Comment: @Dada doesn't that beat the purpose of the `version` pragma?

Comment: `v1.02` is the character with value `1` followed by the character with value `2` (they are not printable; but for instance if you do `say v65.66`, it will print `AB`). Now I don't know about the `version` module, but from what I see on CPAN, isn't the standard way to use it something like `our $VERSION = version->declare("v1.02")` ? @simbabque

Comment: @Dada I was going to say the `declare` part too. Yes.

Comment: `v1.02` (and `v1.2`) produces the same two-character string as `"\x01\x02"`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found this [DOC](https://metacpan.org/pod/perldata#Version-Strings)

```
print v9786;              # prints SMILEY, "\x{263a}"
print v102.111.111;       # prints "foo"
print 102.111.111;        # same
```

Answering to my question:
Despite on that `v1.02` is `v-string` that is not string internally. And when we want to print it we should do extra steps. For example, use module [`version`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/version/lib/version.pm)  as suggested above.

**UPD**
I found next solution ([DOC](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html#vector-flag)):

```
printf "%vd", $VERSION;  # prints "1.2"
```

**UPD**

And [this](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/version/lib/version/Internals.pod#What-about-v-strings?) should be read:

> There are two ways to enter v-strings: a bare number with two or more decimal points, or a bare number with one or more decimal points and a leading 'v' character (also bare). For example:

```
$vs1 = 1.2.3; # encoded as \1\2\3
$vs2 = v1.2;  # encoded as \1\2
```